# In liquid, what are the units "w" and "x"?

Tags: liquid

I'm modifying some Shopify Liquid code and see the following units that don't make sense to me: 1600x 1600w

I'm assuming "w" refers to the width, but are these in pixels? And then I haven't a clue what the "x" refers to.

```
<img  alt="{{ section.settings.image.alt }}"
          {% if section.settings.image != nil %}
            src="{{ section.settings.image | img_url: '100x' }}"
            data-src="{{ section.settings.image | img_url: '2048x' }}"
            class="lazyload lazyload--fade-in hsContainer__image"
            sizes="100vw"
            srcset="  {{ section.settings.image | img_url: '2048x' }} 2048w,
                      {{ section.settings.image | img_url: '1600x' }} 1600w,
                      {{ section.settings.image | img_url: '1200x' }} 1200w,
                      {{ section.settings.image | img_url: '1000x' }} 1000w,
                      {{ section.settings.image | img_url: '800x' }} 800w,
                      {{ section.settings.image | img_url: '600x' }} 600w,
                      {{ section.settings.image | img_url: '400x' }} 400w"
          {% else %}
            src="{{ 'placeholder.svg' | asset_url }}"
            class="hsContainer__image"
          {% endif %}
           />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "w" refers to width of the image as parameter for srcset as described here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Example_3_Using_the_srcset_attribute

The x is used as character delimitating width and height parameters as explained here:
https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/filters/url-filters#size-parameters

HTH